# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: _base64Stream2.default.encode is not a function

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to make this simple api with the help of this article .The primary purpose of reading this article is to learn react native but it starts with a server in nodejs .I couldn't get it running correctly .
Here is the link to article [link](https://rationalappdev.com/offline-first-apps-with-react-native-and-redux/)

Here is the code for server.js file

```
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import giphyapi from 'giphy-api';
import base64 from 'base64-stream';
// Initialize http server
const app = express();

// Register /gif endpoint that returns base64 encoded gif
app.get('/gif', async (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    gif: await fetchGif(),
  });
});

// Launch the server on port 3000
const server = app.listen(3000, () => {
  const { address, port } = server.address();
  console.log(`Listening at http://${address}:${port}`);
});
// Fetch random GIF url with Giphy API, download and Base64 encode it
export const fetchGif = async () => {
    const item = await giphyapi().random('cat');
    return await encode(await download(item.data.image_url));
  };

  // File download helper
const download = async (url) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let req = http.get(url.replace('https', 'http'));
      req.on('response', res => {
        resolve(res);
      });
      req.on('error', err => {
        reject(err);
      });
    });
  };
  // Base64 encode helper
const encode = async (content) => {
    let output = 'data:image/gif;base64,';
    const stream = content.pipe(base64.encode());
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      stream.on('readable', () => {
        let read = stream.read();
        if (read) {
          output += read.toString();
        }
        else {
          resolve(output);
        }
      });
      stream.on('error', (err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
    });
  };
```

Comment: did you `import base64 from 'base64-stream';` ? and did you install it ? `npm install --save base64-stream express giphy-api`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is occurring because the third-party library "base64-stream" does not have the "encoded" function, it may exist in previous versions.

> To solve this problem, you need to change some lines of your code so that your server looks like the code below.

```js
const express = require('express'); // instead of "import express from 'express';"
const http = require('http'); // instead of "import http from 'http';"
const giphyapi = require('giphy-api'); // instead of "import http from 'http';"
const { Base64Encode } = require('base64-stream'); // instead of "import base64 from 'base64-stream';"
// Initialize http server
const app = express();

// Register /gif endpoint that returns base64 encoded gif
app.get('/gif', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const gif = await fetchGif();
    res.json({ gif });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({ error });
  }
});

// Base64 encode helper
const encode = (content) => {
  let output = 'data:image/gif;base64,';
  const stream = content.pipe(new Base64Encode()); // instead of "const stream = content.pipe(base64.encode());"
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    stream.on('readable', () => {
      let read = stream.read();
      if (read) {
        output += read.toString();
      }
      else {
        resolve(output);
      }
    });
    stream.on('error', (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
};

// Launch the server on port 3000
const server = app.listen(3000, () => {
  const { address, port } = server.address();
  console.log(`Listening at http://${address}:${port}`);
});

// Fetch random GIF url with Giphy API, download and Base64 encode it
const fetchGif = async () => {
  try {
    const item = await giphyapi().random('cat');
    const image = await download(item.data.image_url);
    return await encode(image);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('fetchGif', error);
  }
};

// File download helper
const download = (url) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let req = http.get(url.replace('https', 'http'));
    req.on('response', res => {
      resolve(res);
    });
    req.on('error', err => {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Yeah ,it helped and solved the problem .I can continue with my app part now .Thanks man .

Answer (score 0):

`base64-stream` doesn't have any function called `encode(..)`.

There are two Classes `Base64Encode`, `Base64Decode` which are used to stream.